# Battery Saver on Pokemon Go makes Screen go Black with only Logo showing?

Tags: pokemon-go

So, I have a Samsung Galaxy s6 edge in which i downloaded Pokemon Go 2 days ago. I decided to try Battery Save Mode but it ended up making my screen go black with only the Pokemon Logo barely showing through and music playing in the background. I tried facing it down, facing it upward, covering the front and back sensors, tapping my screen like mad in hopes that it would trigger something and make it return to me but to no avail. I don't want to uninstall and re-install because i don't wanna lose my precious Pokemon I walked so much to get :(

Are any of you guys having the same problem? 
Am i dumb and just missed something?

Can anyone help? 
I would really appreciate it guys! Thanks!

Comment: It is supposed to go off power saving if you encounter a Pokémon afaik

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your game progress is saved to the server under your account that you logged in with. You should be able to uninstall and reinstall, then log in with the same account and get your progress back. In theory...

Comment: That is what happens on my S7 as well. Considering some of the issues I've had, I'm starting to think this was developed for iOS and ported to Android.

Comment: Battery saver doesnt do anything for me, my screen just powers off after it's set timeout.

Comment: On the uninstall and reinstall part, all the progress is saved online. I personally uninstalled and reinstalled pokemon go on my phone

Comment: @Kaizerwolf In theory, battery saver turns down screen brightness when teh phone is upside down. If the phone stays upside up, or lies flat on a table, it does nothing.

Comment: I've heard battery saver mode doesn't work properly on Samsung "Edge" devices.

Answer (score 8):

> To make use of Battery Saver, once turned on, simply turn your phone upside down, and the screen will darken to display a faint Pokemon Go logo. The game will still be on, and will still track your movements - you just won't see it. However, you will still get a notification or rumble if you approach a Pokestop or a Pokemon appears, so you can quickly pull the phone out of your pocket to interact!

source: http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Things_Pokemon_Go_Doesn%27t_Tell_You

I tried it and when I turned my phone to the correct position the map appeared again.

In case this is a bug and your game gets stuck in battery saver mode, you don't need to uninstall. You may just go to the running applications list and stop it. When you turn it back on it should be ok and you can just disable battery saving mode. more info on stopping an app: http://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/05/29/how-to-clear-apps-on-the-samsung-galaxy-s6/

I also believe your progress is saved in your account (in a server somewhere), so uninstalling the game will not delete your progress.

Comment: That's a very nice feature, unfortunately it's so buggy that it's useless.

Comment: I have also experienced a bug in which the game would not process touches after getting out of battery saving mode. I friend of mine with a different phone also has this problem. The game simply does not respond to touch (although you still walk and pokemon appear as they normally would) and the solution is to restart the game.

Comment: that's exactly (one of) the problems I have with battery saver. It's totally useless.